# Aden Colony records for Native Yemenis

Tags: birth-records, marriage-records, death-records, family-register, aden

Where can I find **birth**, **death**, and **marriage records**, as well as the **register of persons** for  **Aden Colony** for **Native Yemenis**? As far as I know, the people that I am researching are all **Muslims** by Religion.

I have checked the records for Aden Colony on Ancestry and Findmypast, but they are mainly for  British, European Christians and native converts**. They **do not** hold births, marriages and deaths for Hindus, Muslims, etc.

I am researching the record below:

Records of the British in Aden Colony, 1839-1967 (128 years)